# Single-byte integer type with Hibernate and PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

When using Hibernate with PostgreSQL, I noticed that Java `byte` and low-count `enum` types are represented in the database as `smallint`, a 16-bit integer, and a waste of one byte.

PostgreSQL notoriously lacks an "official" 8-bit integer, but has the oddball semi-undocumented `"char"` type.

Is there a way to setup this mapping in Hibernate in a portable way, so for instance the same code when used on a MySQL database will generate `TINYINT`, but when used on a PostgreSQL instance will generate `"char"`?

Comment: Write a custom `Dialect`.